# Beginner Git merge confuse about two branches

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-diff

I am new to Git, and I'm confused.

Here's an example:

- I build a repo called `prj` in my office.
- I add an image to it and commit to GitHub
- Later, when I back home, I clone this repo, check out a new branch (let's call it `home`) and replace this image with another one with same name.
- Then, after I go back office, I delete the old image, and update the remote branch. Everything seems to work at that stage.
- I use `git diff master origin/home`, which shows a new node added for that image. However, when I run `git merge origin/home`, the image I added at home can not be added to my local master.

Where did I do wrong? How can I do something just like SVN update?

Comment: What do you mean by it 'can not be added'? Did you get an error?

Comment: @Orkster The whole thing is: [1 At office ] I initial repo and put an image and commited. [2 At home ]  I clone it, checkout new branch replace the image with another one, and commit it. [3 back to office ] I remove the image and  try git pull origin master. The image I added at home can not be pull from github to office. 'can not be added' means there is no image at all in my office, only a info shows that the image file I deleted is Changes not staged for commit. What I want to do is remove the local image in office and replace using remote github version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your office computer - don't delete the image. Reset your local changes to the image file, then do the pull. You should see it's content update.

If you still don't see it update, delete the old image, commit the deletion, then try adding the new image again. Sometimes git is weird about replacing files that have the same name.

Comment: Thanks, so what I need to do is:  git reset hello.jpg  and  git pull origin master?

Comment: Yes. The command is actually 'git checkout -- hello.jpg'. Then do the pull.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your changes at your office to the remote branch and then merge the branches.

Comment: thanks, the reason I get confused is this: I just want to use github version to update my current branch, if I commit my change to remote, it will replace github version right?